# Convert Month Name into Number With Different Languages?

Tags: php, localization, strtotime

I want to convert Month Name into Number format with different Languages. I have written one code that code is working on my localhost but its not working on live server its returning false value. And also for some months its working and its not working for **Dezembro** , **outubro** its not working. How i can solve this issue ? Could you please help me to solve this one ??

```
$visit_date = "7 Dezembro, 2019";

 $split_date = explode(" ", $visit_date);  
      $visit_day = sprintf("%02d", $split_date[0]);
      $visit_month = $split_date[1];     

          if (substr($visit_month, -1) == ',')
          {
              $visit_month = substr($visit_month, 0, -1);
              $visit_year =   $split_date[2];   

          }      
          else {
              $visit_year =   $split_date[3];     
          }      

          var_dump($visit_month);
      $visit_month =  month_to_number($visit_month, 'pt_PT');

var_dump($visit_month);



// convert visit date month full name to month number for all languages
function month_to_number($month, $locale_set= 'pt_PT' )
{

    $month  = mb_convert_case($month, MB_CASE_LOWER, 'UTF-8');

    $locale =
        setlocale(LC_TIME, '0');
        setlocale(LC_TIME, $locale_set.'.UTF-8');

    $month_number = FALSE;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
    {
        $time_month     = mktime(0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 1970);
        $short_month    = date('M', $time_month);
        $short_month_lc = strftime('%b', $time_month);

        if (stripos($month, $short_month) === 0 OR
            stripos($month, $short_month_lc) === 0)
        {
            $month_number = sprintf("%02d", $i);

            break;
        }
    }

    setlocale(LC_TIME, $locale); // return locale back

    return $month_number;

}
```

Comment: Not all servers have the same sets of locales available. You should start with a good, thorough read of what the manual for `setlocale` has to say, including the user comments.

Comment: _“that code is working on my localhost but its not working on live server its returning false value.”_ - a developer would start to do some debugging in such a case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can integrate the external class [**dt**](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt) try this:

```
$visit_date = "7 Dezembro, 2019";

dt::setDefaultLanguage('pt');
$dt = dt::create($visit_date);

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');//2019-12-07
```

Internally, the class creates a translation table for every month when setting the language. The [IntlDateFormatter class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) is used for this.

Note: The IntlDateFormatter class works independently of the server's local settings.